# Expression beside ng-repeat make repeater do again unexpectedly

Tags: angularjs

See **Javascript Console Warning** for the issue ( snippet included )

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  app.controller('MainController', function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.data = [{
      name: "John",
      number: 1
    }, {
      name: "Alice",
      number: 2
    }];

    ctrl.nextLetter = function(startChar, index) {
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(startChar.charCodeAt(0) + index);
      console.log("nextLetter() executed: " + letter);
      return letter;
    };

    ctrl.junk = function() {
      console.warn("some junk function invoked without changing any data!");
      console.warn("why nextLetter() execute again ( see below ) ?!");
    };
  });

  app.directive('uSample', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',

      scope: {
        letter: '@'
      },

      link: function(scope) {
        console.log("Do something with " + scope.letter + " in u-sample");
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
u-sample {
  display: block;
  background-color: #88f;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as c">
    <u-sample letter="{{c.nextLetter('i', $index)}}" ng-repeat="item in c.data">
      <span>{{item.name}} ( {{item.number}} )</span>
    </u-sample>

    <button ng-click="c.junk()">Do Junk Function</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a bug. Many digest cycles can run during a scope change. Using a function in the html is not as efficient as providing variables for this reason as the functions might get evaluated many times

Comment: thanks for your comment, but how to prevent digest in specific controller function, something like `preventDefault` in javascript

Comment: What would be the use case for needing that?

Comment: the letter is used for a complicated directive that is child of other directive and have other directive as child. depend on letter, child elements render in different positions.

Comment: then you would be better off building an array or object in controller than using a function if that function might return different values each cycle. would in effect be changing the scope again and can in turn have your code force even more digest cycles

Comment: your approach is simplest way to pass through the problem, but in general this is not a perfect solution. if preventing digest cycle is impossible, there is bad design in angular.

Comment: No..it is part of the efficiency of angular believe it or not. Read up on how angular compiles the DOM and does it's bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution of my own question:**

1. include `angular.js 1.4.3` ( older version may not work )
2. provide `nextLetter` filter ( filters doesn't trigger `$digest` automatically)
3. bind `{{'i' | nextLetter:$index}}` instead of `{{c.nextLetter('i', $index)}}`

**Snippet updated**

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('app', []);
  
  app.filter('nextLetter', function(){
    return function(startChar, index){
      var letter = String.fromCharCode(startChar.charCodeAt(0) + index);
      console.log("nextLetter() executed: " + letter);
      return letter;
    }
  });
  
  app.controller('MainController', function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.data = [{
      name: "John",
      number: 1
    }, {
      name: "Alice",
      number: 2
    }];

    ctrl.junk = function() {
      console.warn("some junk function invoked without changing any data!");
      console.warn("no nextLetter() execute again ( problem solved! ) ");
    };
  });

  app.directive('uSample', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',

      scope: {
        letter: '@'
      },

      link: function(scope) {
        console.log("Do something with " + scope.letter + " in u-sample");
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
u-sample {
  display: block;
  background-color: #88f;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as c">
    <u-sample letter="{{'i' | nextLetter:$index}}" ng-repeat="item in c.data">
      <span>{{item.name}} ( {{item.number}} )</span>
    </u-sample>

    <button ng-click="c.junk()">Do Junk Function</button>
  </div>
</div>
```